# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure after upgrade to TLSv1.2

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, java

I am working on a Java 1.7 application on a Linux Centos server that connects to a third party using SOAP. Everything was working, until the third party upgraded their ssl from TLSv1.1 to TLSv1.2. Now when we try call their service, we get:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking
> https://webservices.abc.company.com: Received fatal alert:
> handshake_failure

We also have another Linux Centos server, that uses the exact same code base, but it can call the SOAP service with no errors. So I have tried to compare to find any differences. The differences I can find, is that some of the directory structures are different, but the files I think are applicable are the same.  For example,

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

Are both in the same place, and both have the same ciphers:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
#SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

They both have the same certificate issued by the third party company.

```
/etc/httpd/ssl/abc.crt
```

I have stopped the firewall.

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

**Question**

Do you know where else I can look, and what I can try?

Comment: `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 my-server.example.com` output for the other side?

Comment: are you using oracle java or openjdk? Also you mention that it is a java client application and a remote SOAP service, but you are showing httpd config files, so you might want to clarify exactly exactly what is connecting to what

Comment: Hi Tom, we are using:  `$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)`

Comment: Our Java 1.7 application has a SOAP client connecting to a 3rd parties SOAP service. The config files I show above are from the SOAP client.  I do not have access to the third parties config files for the SOAP service.

Comment: I have noticed on the server that gets the error, it has:  `echo $MAVEN_OPTS
-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` and the server that has no error: `echo $MAVEN_OPTS
-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=2048m`

Comment: So it looks like from your comment that the java version does not have TLSv1.2 enabled by default and `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` should be added to the MAVEN_OPTS

Comment: The strange thing is `MAVEN_OPTS` has `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` on the server that is not working.

Comment: ah, I misunderstood. Yeah, I would probably put that in `JAVA_OPTS` wherever you are running your java app. How are you running the java app? from command line?

Comment: The app that is having the issue is a Java app running on Apache Karaf. We use Maven to build it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with apache karaf and java version 1.7, so I think it would be better to let someone else try and answer the question ;-)

Comment: Please make sure all the relevant information gets edited into your question. Comments are only temporary, some information can be hard to read in comments, and some people do not see them at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be using a version of Java that has TLS 1.2 support (I'm not sure if 1.7.0_09 falls into that boat, but I know later versions of 1.7 do) and it has to be one of the enabled protocols.  This question has details on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157422/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-in-java-7

Java 1.7 has been EOL since 2015, so upgrading would probably be in the best interest to avoid future issues.

Comment: Thank you. I changed my JAVA_HOME from oracleJDK-1.7 to openJDK-1.7, and now I don't get the error. So it means that openJDK-1.7 supports TLSv1.2.